# Why $ sign shown with every sheet name when importing?

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, vba

I have an Excel sheet which I want to import in SQL server 2012.
The Excel sheet suppose has 3 sheets in it with specific names e, g

- 1.Abc
- 2.ijk
- 3.xyz

When I start import wizard the SQL server import utility shows 6 sheets instead of 3 like this with $ sign included.

- 1.Abc
- 2.abc$
- 3.ijk
- 4.ijk$......

I want to know why it shows $ sign with each sheet and which one is real sheet? Which one should I import?

Comment: Why don't you just try it both ways (with and without the `$`) and see which one works?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know why it shows $ sign with each sheet and which one is real sheet ?

I have never seen anything like you mentioned. I always see sheets with `$`. Here is a screenshot

[image]

> which one should i import?

Use the one with `$`. That is what we use while importing (via wizard or via code)

`INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\MyNewFile.xls','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')`